# Elements of nth level of binary tree

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

How to find all elements of given level of binary tree?
I tried with this:

```ml
nlevel(void,_,[]).
nlevel(tree(X,L,R),0,[X]).
nlevel(tree(X,L,R),N,Zs):-
   nlevel(L,N1,Xs),
   nlevel(R,N1,Ys),
   append(Xs,Ys,Zs),
   N is N1+1.
```

, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I don't have access to Prolog to check)

```ml
nlevel(void, _, []).
nlevel(tree(X,L,R), 0, [X]).    % (* end of recursion *)
nlevel(tree(X,L,R), N, Zs):-
   N > 0,
   N1 is N-1,                   % (* go one more step down, with N known *)
   nlevel(L, N1, Xs),
   nlevel(R, N1, Ys),
   append(Xs, Ys, Zs).          % (* possible to use difference lists to append *)
```

Updated thanks to Will Ness!

Comment: I'd add `N > 0` as the first goal to the third clause. then the (green) cut in the 2nd clause isn't needed anymore.